# How do I execute a command if only one player is present on a scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing on bedrock and I'm making a UHC map. I have a scoreboard set up where it lists everyone still alive, and once people die they get taken off the scoreboard. I want a command to test when only one person is left on the scoreboard. This last survivor would be the winner and I would like to have a title appear when they win.

For my UHC I have a repeating command block setting the players spawn point inside an enclosed bedrock box. When the player dies and spawns in this box, they land on a pressure plate resetting their score on the alive scoreboard, hence taking their name off the display. After their score is reset, the are teleported into a room where they have the option to spectate.

Comment: It would substantially improve this post if you could [edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/371060/edit) it to provide the commands that you have already used. That way we can tailor our answers to your context!

Comment: Are you the same person who [suggested an edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/291312) to this question? If yes, see https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command /execute store result score players playerCount if entity @e[type=player,scores={deaths=0..0}] what this will do is store the amount of players in a scoreboard. Make sure to add playerCount as a scoreboard

Comment: This form of the execute command only works on Java edition at the time this question was asked. The question is tagged for bedrock edition.

Comment: oh yea sorry didnt notice that.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer has the right idea, but wrong execution for bedrock.

Adjust your current scoreboard so every player on it has a value of one.

```
/scoreboard objectives add alive dummy
/scoreboard players set @a alive 1
```

Create a variable to hold the total.

```
/scoreboard objectives add alive_total dummy
```

When players respawn on the pressure plate, reset their score.

```
/scoreboard players reset @p[r=2] alive
```

Have a repeating command block chain with the following commands:

```
/scoreboard players set total alive_total 0
/scoreboard players operation total alive_total += @a alive
/scoreboard players test total alive_total 1 1
```

Then chain the logic you want to run at the end of that command chain. Be sure to make the chain conditional.